# Python. Связь между экземплярами одного класса через обращение к атрибуту

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, pygame

Есть один класс. Есть два экземпляра этого класса.
Один движется (`self.type = 'move'`), второй не движется (`self.type = 'stay'`).

Нужно, чтобы второй тоже двигался по координатам первого.

Может ли `obj2` апеллируя атрибутом `self.type` обратиться к `obj1`, чтобы наследовать его координаты?

Вариант посредника в виде глобальной переменной известен, но нужно чтобы `obj2` обращался непосредственно к `obj1`.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

UPD: Важно, чтобы обращение происходило внутри класса, в методе Update, учитывая, что никакая информация вроде названий или индексов копий неизвестна, известен только атрибут self.type.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = WINDOW_SIZE = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

objects = []

class ObjectTest:
    def __init__(self, type, x, y):
        objects.append(self)

        self.type = type

        self.color = 'red'
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 64, 64)

    def update(self):
        if self.type == 'move':
            self.rect.x += 1
            self.color = 'green'
        if self.type == 'stay':
            # здесь нужно self.rect.x взять у копии с тайпом 'move'
            self.color = 'white'

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)

obj1 = ObjectTest('move', 100, 100)
obj2 = ObjectTest('stay', 200, 200)

play = True
while play:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            play = False
            pygame.quit()

    for i in objects: i.update()

    window.fill('black')
    for i in objects: i.draw()


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Женя, sorry, я не понимаю ни ваш комментарий, ни то что вы написали в UPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме переменных **экземпляра** класса (то есть `self`) есть ещё переменные самого класса `ObjectTest`. Вы можете поместить список `objects` в переменные класса `ObjectTest` и при этом обращаться к нему через `self`, то есть через экземпляр класса (экземпляры имеют доступ к переменным класса):

```py
class ObjectTest:
    # список объектов теперь принадлежит всем объектам класса
    objects = []

    def __init__(self, type, x, y):
        # добавляем новый экземпляр класса в список объектов класса
        self.objects.append(self)
    ...

    def update(self):
        if self.type == 'move':
            self.rect.x += 1
            self.color = 'green'
        if self.type == 'stay':
            # перебираем объекты класса, ищем движущийся объект
            for obj in self.objects:
                # если нашли, то копируем его координату
                if obj.type == 'move':
                    self.rect.x = obj.rect.x
            self.color = 'white'
```

Внешне это выглядит похоже на использование глобальной переменной, но является более правильным подходом - список `objects` лежит не в глобальном пространстве, где непонятно, к чему он вообще относится, а лежит в классе, объекты которого он содержит.

Можно пойти дальше и, если у вас только по одному объекту каждого `type`, то завести словарь, а не список, у которого ключом будет `type` объекта. Тогда вам даже не нужно будет перебирать объекты, чтобы найти нужный:

```py
class ObjectTest:
    # словарь объектов
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, type, x, y):
        # добавляем новый экземпляр класса в словарь объектов класса
        self.objects[type] = self
    ...

    def update(self):
        if self.type == 'move':
            self.rect.x += 1
            self.color = 'green'
        if self.type == 'stay':
            # ищем движущийся объект (он может быть ещё не добавлен)
            obj = self.objects.get('move')
            if obj in not None:
                # если нашли, то копируем его координату
                self.rect.x = obj.rect.x
            self.color = 'white'
```

И `type` - плохое название для параметра функции, оно перекрывает встроенную функцию. Используйте `type_`. Вот в переменных класса можно оставить `self.type` как есть, насколько я помню.

Comment: Про переменные самого класса не знал, благодарю за информацию. Получается, есть еще вариант назначить переменную класса, в которую копия 'move' будет отсылать данные, а копия 'stay' забирать их. Изначально тестовый вариант так и работал, только посредником служила глобальная переменная. Цель данной миссии была исключить зависимость от глобал переменных

Comment: @ЖеняНевейко Да, если вам от того объекта нужна только переменная `x`, то имеет смысл сделать переменную `x` в классе и работать чисто с ней, `objects` тогда и не нужен. Главное принцип понять, а реализации можно разные сделать. Хотя тут может быть сложность в том, что скалярные переменные копируются по значению и через `self.x` вы переменную класса уже не получите,  вернее не выставите. Нужно будет обращаться к этой переменной как `ObjectTest.x` и при её записи и при чтении.

Comment: Угу, через self.x обратиться не получилось, но вариант через ObjectTest.x работает. Также (не знаю зачем) отработал практику записи названия класса в переменную экземпляра класса и вариант обращения через self.имя_класса.x тоже работает

Answer (score 0):

Я видимо не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать.

1. Может вам просто добавить эту строку:

   `self.rect.x += 1` в методе `update()`
2. Или добавьте строку:

   `objects[1].rect.x = objects[0].rect.x`

---

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = WINDOW_SIZE = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

objects = []

class ObjectTest:
    def __init__(self, type, x, y):
        objects.append(self)

        self.type = type

        self.color = 'red'
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 64, 64)

    def update(self):
        if self.type == 'move':
            self.rect.x += 1
            self.color = 'green'
        if self.type == 'stay':
            self.color = 'white'
            
# ?          self.rect.x += 1    # может вам просто добавить эту строку ?

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)
        

obj1 = ObjectTest('move', 100, 100)
obj2 = ObjectTest('stay', 200, 200)
obj3 = ObjectTest('123', 300, 300)

play = True
while play:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            play = False
#            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    for i in objects: 
        i.update()

    window.fill('black')           
    for i in objects: 
        i.draw()

        objects[1].rect.x = objects[0].rect.x       # или попробуйте так 

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внёс в вопрос уточнения. Задача не "заставить двигаться любой ценой", а "двигаться по точным координатам первой копии, спрашивая их у первой копии, зная о первой копии только атрибут self.type" (для сравнения: двигаться как башня танка с шасси).  Нужно, чтобы обращение происходило внутри класса в методе update по атрибуту self.type- это единственная доступная инфа, которой копия номер 2 может пользоваться по отношению к копии номер 1